# Как Google API понимает, какое приложение к нему подключено?

Tags: java, android, google-api

У меня есть аккаунт в Google API Console, я там зарегистрировал `OAuth2.0` для <kbd>LogIn</kbd>-кнопки, во время регистрации. Я так понимаю, что единственное уникальное значение, которое связано с моим приложением, и которое я регистрирую при открытии аккаунта, это `package name`.

Но что будет, если другой пользователь тоже откроет аккаунт и тоже зарегистрирует мой `package name`?

Как тогда будет вести себя приложение при логине?

Причина вопроса в том, что для того, чтоб получить `tokenId` от Google для отправки для проверки на сервер, нужно, чтоб и приложение и web-сервис были под одним `OAuth2.0`-аккаунтом...

На данный момент они используют разные аккаунты, и я не могу понять: для того, чтоб поместить их под один аккаунт, мне просто нужно в аккаунте web-сервис зарегистрировать, приложение и всё? Но как тогда Google поймет, чем отличается регистрация приложения / web-сервиса в моём аккаунте? Ведь они имеют одинаковые данные...

Comment: два раза один package name использовать невозможно. Это уникальный идентификатор приложения.

Comment: @metalurgus да но вчера я зашел на аккаунт на котором зарегистрирован сервер и нормально зарегистрировал там в `OAuth2.0` приложение с таким же  `package name` как и в моем аккаунте...

Comment: @metalurgus я так понимаю, что вообще единственое по чем распознает гугл какое приложение к нему обращается через `google logIn` это `package name` , верно?

Comment: @metalurgus может дело в SHA1 ключах? ведь его я тоже указываю...